# Synfony3: How to work with assets and path

Tags: php, css, symfony

Hello everyone: i'm deploying my project. Pointed the URL to the web folder when I call the url the login page shows but with non css or js, and the buttons calls doesn't work.
This is how I call the css/js or links to some path

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="{{path('add')}}">add</a>
```

and this is what it translate

```
<link href="/project/web/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and that should translate it as

```
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any help?
thanks

Comment: [Creating css, js, image like assets in a symfony application and accessing them in twig template](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/qau5/creating-css-js-image-like-assets-in-a-symfony-application-and-accessing-them-in-twig-template) and [Using symfony AsseticBundle for asset management in twig](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/rtdl/using-symfony-assetic-bundle-for-asset-management-in-twig)

Comment: I managed adding into config.yml this    assets:
        base_urls: {real_url}. But I can´t do that for path()

Comment: Is `add` your route name? https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#linking-to-pages

Comment: yes add is the name

Comment: Run `app/console debug:router` to see if `add` exists or not.

Comment: it return it ok: add                         ANY      ANY      ANY    /u/add/{id}

Comment: it works locally but when I use the domain, starts the problems

Comment: Try to provide `id` property as well in path.

Comment: yes, but that not the problem. the problem is when it generate the url it start with /project/web when it should be /